# No SQL Services in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, service

I just installed SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. Now I'm attempting to log on to a database using Windows authentication. I'm getting an error. Error 26. I checked my services and I don't have any SQL related services in my list. There are also no Services in the MS SQL server Configuration Management tool.
Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: **Management Studio** is ***ONLY*** the management GUI ! It is ***NOT*** the database engine! You need to install the **SQL Server database engine**; too, in order to connect to it!

Comment: Is it free to download? All I can find is SQL Server 2014 Express..

Comment: @Rosario, SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition is now free for Dev Essentials members.  See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/.  Note that Developer Edition has the same features as Enterprise Edition but may be licensed only for development and testing.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server **Express** is free for any kind of usage - even commercial